# Does chrome fully support performance API for all resources entries?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Is this a bug in the latest version of chrome - 29.0.1547.76 m?
When you raise an xmlhttprequest, lets say while downloading an image, you can see that the resource is downloaded with status code 200 OK in network tab, but the performance.getEntries() or performance.getEntriesByName(resourceUrl) doesn't list the resource entry. When the page load is complete and you evaluate performance.getEntriesByName(resourceUrl) in console, it lists the image entry properly. So, there is a lag in chrome while populating the resource entries in performance object?
In IE10, this works perfectly fine.

Comment: What's the question?